# Loading data taking too much time CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am facing problems when i tries to save 40,000 records into `CoreData` Entity.

I am getting 40,000 records by consuming the webservice using `AFNetworking`, the response is in JSON. Than i divide the data into 4 , 10000 record chunks and then assign these 4 chunks to separate `NSOperation` objects (i have created subclass of `NSOperation`) and add these `NSOperation` Objects to `NSOperationQueue`.

The problem is that this way it is taking too much time to save the data into `CoreData`. And i want to find a solution where i can load the data very quickly.

This is the code in which i am creating `NSOperation` objects and adding them to `NSOperationQueue`.

```
 - (void)casesResponseReceived:(NSArray*)array
{
 id responseObject = [array objectAtIndex:0];
 NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [array objectAtIndex:1];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *response = [responseString JSONValue];

NSString *responseStr = [response JSONRepresentation];
NSRange range = [responseStr rangeOfString:@"["];
int index = 0;
int objectsCount = 5000;
if (range.location == 0) {
    NSInteger count = objectsCount;
    totalOperationsCount = 0;
    completedOperationsCount = 0;
    self.myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    while (count == objectsCount) {
        if ((index+count) > [response count]) {
            count = [response count] - index;
        }
        NSArray *subArray = [response subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, count)];
        index += objectsCount;

        CaseParseOperation *operation = [[CaseParseOperation alloc] initWithData:subArray MOC:moc];
        operation.delegate = self;
        totalOperationsCount++;
        [self.myQueue addOperation:operation];

    }

    /*
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(serviceHelperDidCasesReceivedSuccessful:)]) {
        [self.delegate serviceHelperDidCasesReceivedSuccessful:self];
    }*/
}
else {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(serviceHelperDidCasesReceivedFailed:)]) {
        [self.delegate serviceHelperDidCasesReceivedFailed:self];
    }
}}
```

CaseOperation.h

```
@class CaseParseOperation;

@protocol CaseParseOperationProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)caseParseOperationDidOperationComplete: (CaseParseOperation*)caseParseOperation;
 @end
 @interface CaseParseOperation : NSOperation
 @property (nonatomic, weak) id<CaseParseOperationProtocol> delegate;
 -(id)initWithData:(NSArray*)parseData MOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc;
 @end
```

CaseOperation.m

```
@interface CaseParseOperation()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *casesData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *localMOC;
@end

@implementation CaseParseOperation

- (id)initWithData:(NSArray*)parseData MOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
{
 self = [super init];
 if (self) {
    self.casesData = [parseData copy];
    self.mainMOC = moc;
 }
  return self;
 }
- (void)main
 {
@autoreleasepool {
    self.localMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    self.localMOC.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.mainMOC.persistentStoreCoordinator;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                 name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object: self.localMOC];


    [self parseData];
}
}
-(void) mergeChanges: (NSNotification*) saveNotification {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.mainMOC mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
});

if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(caseParseOperationDidOperationComplete:)]) {
    [self.delegate caseParseOperationDidOperationComplete:self];
}

}

- (void)parseData
{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Case" inManagedObjectContext:self.localMOC];
fetchRequest.entity = ent;

NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"caseNumber == $caseNumber"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

//NSMutableArray *insertedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in self.casesData) {
    if (self.isCancelled) {
        break;
    }
    NSString *desc = [dic valueForKey:@"description"];
    BOOL enabled = [[dic valueForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue];
    NSString *billToCustomerNo = [dic valueForKey:@"billToCustomerNo"];
    NSString *caseNo = [dic valueForKey:@"caseNo"];
    NSString *billToName = [dic valueForKey:@"billToName"];
    NSString *personResponsible = [dic valueForKey:@"personResponsible"];

    NSDictionary *variables = @{ @"caseNumber" : caseNo };
    fetchRequest.predicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:variables];

    NSArray *matchedObj = [self.localMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    if ([matchedObj count] > 0) {
        Case *caseObj = [matchedObj objectAtIndex:0];
        caseObj.isEnabled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:enabled];
        caseObj.caseDescription = desc;
        caseObj.customerNumber = billToCustomerNo;
        caseObj.customerName = billToName;
        caseObj.personResponsible = personResponsible;
    }
    else {

        /*
        Case *caseObj = [[Case alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Case"
                                                                 inManagedObjectContext:self.localMOC] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
        caseObj.caseNumber = caseNo;
        caseObj.customerName = billToName;
        caseObj.customerAddress = @"";
        caseObj.customerPhone = @"";
        caseObj.caseDescription = desc;
        caseObj.customerNumber = billToCustomerNo;
        caseObj.isEnabled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:enabled];
        caseObj.personResponsible = personResponsible;

        [insertedObjects addObject:caseObj];
        */
        [Case createObjectWithCaseNumber:caseNo customerName:billToName customerAddress:@"" customerPhone:@"" caseDescription:desc customerNumber:billToCustomerNo isEnabled:enabled personResponsible:personResponsible MOC:self.localMOC];
    }
}

/*
if ([insertedObjects count] > 0) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL isInserted = [self.localMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:insertedObjects error:&error];
    if (error || !isInserted) {
        NSLog(@"Error occured");
    }
}
*/

if ([self.localMOC hasChanges]) {
    [self.localMOC save:nil];
}

}

@end
```

Comment: What is the size of your response string?

Comment: @FawadMasud 6782818 bytes.

Comment: Profile with instruments, find the slowest parts, consider shipping a starter database instead of downloading and parsing a huge data set.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is run Instruments and find the bottlenecks, as @jrturton recommends.

But there's one huge glaring bottleneck that's apparent from reading the code. To avoid duplicates, you're doing a fetch-- for every incoming instance. With 40k records you'll have to do 40k fetches during the import process, and that's going to be slow no matter what.

You can improve that by processing the data in batches:

1. Get a bunch of `caseNumber` values into an array
2. Do a fetch with a predicate of `caseNumber IN %@`, with the array as the argument.
3. Use that array to check for duplicates.

You'll need to experiment a little to see how many "a bunch" is in step 1. Higher numbers mean fewer fetches, which is good for speed. But higher numbers also mean more memory use.

For a more detailed discussion, see Apple's [Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) guide, especially the section named "Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys valuable suggestions. But i have solved that issue by just altering some technique in the `parseData` function.

```
-(void)parseData
  {
   NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"caseNumber == $caseNumber"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

    NSArray *allCases = [Case getAllCaseObjectsWithMOC:self.localMOC];

    for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in self.casesData) {
        if (self.isCancelled) {
            break;
        }
        NSString *caseNo = [dic valueForKey:@"caseNo"];
        NSDictionary *variables = @{ @"caseNumber" : caseNo };

        predicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:variables];

        NSArray *matchedObj = [allCases filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        if ([matchedObj count] == 0) {
            NSString *desc = [dic valueForKey:@"description"];
            BOOL enabled = [[dic valueForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue];
            NSString *billToCustomerNo = [dic valueForKey:@"billToCustomerNo"];

            NSString *billToName = [dic valueForKey:@"billToName"];
            NSString *personResponsible = [dic valueForKey:@"personResponsible"];
            [Case createObjectWithCaseNumber:caseNo customerName:billToName customerAddress:@"" customerPhone:@"" caseDescription:desc customerNumber:billToCustomerNo isEnabled:enabled personResponsible:personResponsible MOC:self.localMOC];

        }
    }

       if ([self.localMOC hasChanges]) {
        [self.localMOC save:nil];
    }    
 }
```

Comment: If your database gets bigger, this may use too much memory as you fetch all the `Case` objects. You can use `fetchBatchSize` property of `NSFetchRequest` to reduce memory usage.

Comment: That solves the problem in part by not doing any fetches at all. If you don't need to check for duplicates, that's certainly faster, but if there's any chance of duplicates then you're not going to catch them with this code.

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes you are right, we have to remove fetchrequest because there was no need to check for duplicates as the response from server contains only news records.

Comment: @TomHarrington Ok if i wanted to check for duplicates can you help me modify the code so it will work fine for checking duplicates as well. I have checked that apple document i am confused in that check and create part.